# concatenating arrays, array 1 memory gone C++

Tags: c++, arrays, concatenation

Program consists of array1[20] and array2[40] from input files. Array1 is then added on to the end of array2 (after which they will be sorted chronologically, but I havent gotten there yet bc I am stuck on this). The final result will be printed; I did not include this portion of the code nor the code for inputing files to make it easier for you to read :) thanks for the help.

The code yeilds no errors. The input is number 1 through 20 on both input files and the output reads

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 135062784 135305664 134511120 135308884 6 0 6 16 135303844 134511520 134511136 134957510 135308884 135111932 135120188 0 134511156 135303952 134511168 134805750

```
int readSortedArray (int array[20], int count, istream& infile)
{   
count = 0;
while( (count < 20) && (infile >> array[count]) )
{
    count++;
}

return count;
}

int main ()
{
 int array[20], array1[20], array2[40];
 int count, count1, count2, x;

count1 = readSortedArray(array1, count1, infile1);
count2 = readSortedArray(array2, count2, infile2);

 for (int i=1; i < count1 + 1; i++ )
   {
       array1[i - 1] >> array2[count2 + i];
   }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code shouldn't produce any output. Are you sure it does?

Comment: i removed the code for printing the array in my question to make it less cluttered and easier to read @immibis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the for loop in the main function should be this (i should start at 0). And make sure infile2 really contains what you think it contains.

```
for (int i=0; i < count1; i++ )
{
  array2[count2 + i] = array1[i];
}
```